# Axios Get request to show in browser

Tags: javascript, html, api

```
axios.get("https://swapi.co/api/people")
    .then(response => {
        for(let i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++){
            const h1 = document.createElement('h1')
            h1.textContent = response.data[i].name
            document.body.appendChild(h1)
        }
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
```

I am trying to get this api link to create a list in browser, showing the names. I have gotten this to work with a free api from VSchool that I was able to create myself with Post request. But now that I have Swapi in there to show Star Wars characters, nothing will show. My logic for it all hasn't changed though. Am I missing something? Thank you

Comment: I think the response might not be in the same format as before. Can you do a console.log of response and response.data.. I have a feeling that you either need response.results or response.data.results to get what you need

Comment: Always check that variables actually contain what you think they contain. A simple `console.log(response.data)` would've shown what the issue is: the API reply is an object, and the array of people is found in `.results`: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/0xp3ondg/

Answer (score 0):

You are using improper response format. Add response.results instead of response.data -

```
axios.get("https://swapi.co/api/people")
.then(response => {
    for(let i = 0; i < response.results.length; i++){
        const h1 = document.createElement('h1')
        h1.textContent = response.results[i].name
        document.body.appendChild(h1)
    }
})
.catch(error => console.log(error))
```